# How do I combine multiple if (stringname.equals("value"))?

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, equals

I have multiple strings that have to have a certain value to trigger the notification, but I can't seem to find a way to combine them

```
String wppanswer,tbanswer,ctanswer,ssowpanswer,cppanswer;
if  (wppanswer.equals("Yes"))
            (tbanswer.equals("Yes"))
            (ctanswer.equals("Yes"))
            (ssowpanswer.equals("Yes"))
            (ssowpanswer.equals("N/A"))
            (cppanswer.equals("Yes")){

                NotificationCompat.Builder Yes =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.adccube)
                                .setContentTitle("Success!")
                                .setContentText("YEY! You have everything you need, proceed with work");
                int mNotificationId = 001;
                NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, Yes.build());
            }
```

Thank you all in advance, if I need to provide more information, I can do

EDIT I've tried the below threads to no avail

[Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761676/combine-multiple-if-statements)

[Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791518/compare-two-strings-with-equals-dont-work)

[Thread 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208052/string-equals-with-multiple-conditions-and-one-action-on-result)

Comment: Have you heard of OR (`||`) and AND (`&&`)?

Comment: make it more nullsafe and swap the equals: "Yes".equals(tbanswer)
However... your code will never compile.

Comment: @Eran i knew the OR but not the AND, also couldn't seem to phrase the question right when searching for it either. Thanks muchly

Comment: When it comes to String comparison with equals it's often better to write the comparisons the other way around. So instead of `wppanswer.equals("Yes")` you would write `"Yes".equals(wppanswer)` this doesnt solve your problem but saves you a lot of nullpointer checks. For concatenating different expressions you should use `&&` (and) or `||` (or). These are boolean operators that you can use to say something like `if (X && Y)` (both X and Y have to be true) or `if (X || Y)` (only one has to be true).

Comment: @Aron_dc thanks for the advice, always good to learn something new, i shall edit my existing code, and use in the future

Comment: @Marcusswitch No problem. It's always fun to share a bit of knowledge, even if it is that basic. Which let's me puzzling how on earth you are a application developer and never heard of `||` or `&&` or seemingly boolean logic at all ?!?

Comment: @Aron_dc I started this job doing something completely different. As the jobs gone on, i've been pushed into doing this kind of thing, and having to learn as i go along. Although the more i do, the more i've been enjoying it

Comment: But in waht condition you want show notification , i mean you want to satisfy all the condition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use logical `AND`, which is `&&` in Java, to make the if block code executed only if all the conditions are true, like:

```
if (wppanswer.equals("Yes") &&
        tbanswer.equals("Yes") &&
        ctanswer.equals("Yes") &&
        ssowpanswer.equals("Yes") &&
        ssowpanswer.equals("N/A") &&
        cppanswer.equals("Yes")){
    //your code here        
}
```

Furthermore, as it's yet said in comments, it is better to use `"Yes".equals(wppanswer)` style in your code, to prevent the `NullPointerException` if your `wppanswer` or any other object will be NULL, while you call it's `equals()` method.

Answer (score 1):

To make code more readable, consider refactoring to the helper method:

```
// returns true if and only if all objects are equal to each other
public static boolean allEquals(Object first, Object... rest) {
    for (Object o : rest)
        if (!Objects.equals(first, o))  // `Objects#equals` to avoid NPE 
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then use it in main code:

```
if (allEquals("Yes", wppanswer, tbanswer, ctanswer, ssowpanswer, cppanswer) 
    && "N/A".equals(ssowpanswer)) {
    // trigger action
}
```